# how to divide the image view into different number of section or portions in android studio

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to divide the `Imageview` into different number of sections and all these sections are clickable and will open a new activity.

Sample `ImageView` which I'll try to divided into 47 different sections.

[image: Sample ImageView which I'll try to divided into 47 different sections.]

Comment: Use a GridView with a background image. And transparent TextViews to be used as "Buttons".

Comment: will I used 47 background images?

Comment: Did I tell you so? I told you: `... with **1** background image`. Since the TextViews will be transparent, you'll see through them. And you'll see their parent's background.

Comment: It's just a sample imageview I have 48 images with different number of sections???  It's to diffivcult to make all background image with all section.

Comment: Then use an image for all your Buttons. You may prefer to use a GridLayout instead of a GridView, because the cells can have fifferent sizes.

Comment: hold on sir..... these all images are caming from server so I don't know the width and height of particular portion in the image view....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of 47 Rect that define the sections and in onTouch handler test if some of the Rect contains the touched point coordinates

```
private ArrayList<Rect> rectsArray = new ArrayList<>;

// add to the array 47 Rect with coordinates of sections 


// in onTouch handler
int touchedRect = -1;  // -1 means point is outside any section
for (int i == 0; i < 47 ; i++){
    if (rectsArray.get(i).contains(X, Y)){
       touchedRect = i;
       break;
      }
    }
```